# Verify if user has entered valid data type

Tags: java

I want to check that the data entered by the user via terminal is the correct type needed in the program. If it is not, the code should loop so it asks for the data again before proceeding to the next step.

Example:

The message in terminal is as follows:

> Enter Number:

and the user enters a string such as

> yes

How can I loop the program and ask for the number again until the user enters a number of type `double`?

The code so far for this is:

```
System.out.println("Enter number:");
double number = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: @VicoPelaez please accept some answers. people spend effort and time for your problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
double number;

try
{
   number = scanner.nextDouble();
   number = parseDouble(inputString);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{
   System.out.println("Please enter a valid double!");
   number = scanner.nextDouble();
   number = parseDouble(inputString);
   // if the input is not valid again, you need a loop, rethink.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using `Scanner`, you could use `Scanner.hasDouble()`. To ensure that you do get a valid double, some looping mechanism *will* be necessary:

```
boolean numberFound = false;
while (!numberFound) {
   if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
    number = input.nextDouble();
    numberFound = true;
   } else {
    System.out.println("Invalid double " + input.next());
   }
}
```